# How can I filter a String-Array in Android Developement?

Tags: android, filter, arrays

I wanted to know if their is any way you can automatically filter a `String-array`. Basically, I have two `spinners`, In the 1st `spinner`, you have a list of 50 US states. The second has All all the `US Colleges`. When User selects a state, the 2nd filter is automatically filter to show colleges in the state that the user selects. How can I do this and Is it best to use a `String-Array`, Is their another way? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Just coming by with a tip. If you have an `Adapter` you would want to "filter" on, Android has a nifty interface called `Filterable` which you can call a `Filter` on. See here [in the Developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html)

Comment: I tried a string-array with all states and then couple of other string-arrays with the list of coleges in a certain state then then when ever user selelts a certain state that specific string array will appear

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/).

This will give you basic idea about spinner.

**1st**
In above example in res/values
 1. Create string array that will store all your states
 2. Then you have to manage separate list of colleges in `ArrayList`
 3. Write your list selection login in listner `OnItemSelectedListener` whose method is `onItemSelected()`

**2nd**
 According to your requirement by using just two arrays of `string` its quite difficult I say.
From my perspective it will be better if you manage separate `string-arrays` for different state's colleges.